# what is a faithfully exact functor?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

Could any of you give me a definition of faithfully exact functor, please?

Comment: I think it's a functor which both preserves and reflects short exact sequences, but I can't find a reference which actually says this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Indeed a functor $F:\mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{B}$ of abelian categories is called faithfully exact if the following holds: A sequence $A\to B\to C$ in $\mathcal{A}$ is exact if and only if the induced sequence $F(A)\to F(B)\to F(C)$ in $\mathcal{B}$ is exact.

See for example Ishikawa, *[Faithfully exact functors and their applications to projective modules and injective modules](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.nmj/1118801336)*, available on Project Euclid. There you can also find equivalent reformulations.

The motivation for this terminology is probably the following: Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ an $R$-module. Then the functor $M\otimes_R -$ is exact if and only if $M$ is flat and it is *faithfully* exact if and only if $M$ is *faithfully* flat.

Comment: I like "reflects exactness" better :)

Comment: @Philipp: thank you for your answer. Could you tell me, please, also the definition of faithfully flat?

Comment: Actually what I've written in the last paragraph is usually used as the definition of faithfully flat. Theorem 1.1 of Ishikawa's paper applied to this situation provides some equivalent definitions. See also the reference to [Bourbaki, Algèbre commutative] given in the footnote to the proof of Theorem 1.1 in Ishikawa's paper.

Comment: Since a functor is faithful iff it reflects exact sequences (Popescu, *Abelian Categories with Applications to Rings and Modules*, exercise 4 at page 68) and it is exact iff it preserves exact sequences, I was convinced that the name *faithfully exact* should stand for *faithful and exact* (in the same way as *fully faithful* stands for *full and faithful*).